# GWT real vs redirected URL

Tags: url, gwt, redirect

I have an OVH hosted application on `http://ovhserver/myapp/`

This application is also accessible via http://anyUser.domain.com. I did this by redirecting *.domain.com to `http://ovhserver/myapp/`

The browser displays the `http://[anyUser].domain.com`. But when I try to read it using GWT, I'm only getting the real adress (`http://ovhserver/myapp/`).

[anyUser] is a reference to the active account; If you create an account X, my application would be accessible via `http://X.domain.com`.

I tryed, in vain, using GWT.getHostPageBaseURL(), Window.Location.getHref() and Window.Location.getPath().

I want to read the "displayed" URL in the browser. How can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not *redirection*, most likely `anyUser.domain.com` loads `ovhserver/myapp` in a frame. You can try using `$wnd.top.location.href` in a JSNI method though I'm not sure you'll be given access to it (as it's a cross-origin access).

You should really try setting up a *true* domain/hosting, it doesn't cost much, and would save you many headaches that *framing* will doubtlessly create.